# Put a half-baked paper in arXiv for the purpose of documentation

Tags: arxiv

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I didn't find it.

I have been working on a side project for some time, but I don't have the time to make the final evaluations to make it into a peer-reviewed-worthy paper. However, I do think it has merit and I wouldn't want it going to waste.

Is publishing in arXiv for this purpose considered acceptable?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25939/is-github-adequate-for-purposes-of-giving-a-manuscript-a-timestamp-to-protect-ag

Comment: Also related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/is-it-good-for-academic-path-if-i-publish-too-many-papers-in-arxiv

Comment: And Nate's answer in http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16791/is-it-possible-to-upload-expository-papers-to-arxiv?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ArXiv.org is a *preprint* server.  It is *not intended* for your purposes.

Even though people do upload all kinds of documents (half baked ideas, their PhD thesis, lecture notes, ...), I personally think it *inappropriate*.

You might consider putting it on your website, or even emailing it to people who are likely to be interested.  Or, make time to finish it!

Comment: PhD theses and lecture notes are completely appropriate for arXiv.  (I'm a moderator.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is rather surprising to me; I always though that people use arXiv as an online technical report database, in which researchers can upload material either right before publication, or an extended version (that may not satisfy all requirements of the publication) that authors may reference in their peer-reviewed papers...

Comment: _I always though that people use arXiv as an online technical report database_ — They do.  But lecture notes and PhD theses are regularly published as technical reports.  And authors can and regularly do reference lecture notes and PhD theses in their peer-reviewed papers.

Comment: @JeffE: going by http://arxiv.org/help/moderation, I'm afraid some PhD theses and lecture notes do not agree with arXiv policy.  You, as moderator, get the final say though :)

Comment: @yoki, some people do use arXiv like this, and it can be a benefit to the community.  Also, people upload shorter documents, and again these can be useful (the example I have in mind is http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3924).  But I think these are rather the exception to the rule.

Comment: @JeffE, just to expand my previous comment:  "arXiv accepts only submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue [...]".  I personally expand this to include books that would be accepted by a decent publisher after refereeing.  So some PhD theses and lectures notes are OK.  But they should contain substantive new material (not a problem with theses, hopefully!), and be in a book-ish format (not the case with a "stapled" thesis, for example).  That's my view anyway, but I'm not an arXiv mod so it's irrelevant :D

Comment: ([arXiv even accepts joke papers](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/86346/452))