# Is it ok to upload joke papers to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

I have recently stumbled upon this paper on arXiv: 
 [Stopping GAN Violence: Generative Unadversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02528)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311232135/https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02528)), which is a parody/joke paper.

Is it ok to upload joke papers to arXiv?

Comment: viXra would be a better place for joke papers.

Comment: I think it is okay when the paper is extremely funny, like the one you have linked.

Comment: OK, according to whom?

Comment: @MadJack arXiv policy.

Comment: It is interesting to observe that the cultural split in the answers here, between _Oh April Fools Day is all good fun!_ and _This just creates a mess that impacts other people._, is the same as at Wikipedia.

Comment: To those in the know, "Under review as a conference paper at SIGBOVIK 2017" is also a strong indicator, [SIGBOVIK](http://sigbovik.org/) being the Association for Computational Heresy's annual conference held on or around April 1 in in Pittsburgh.

Comment: I am surprised (not unpleasantly...) to see such a long list of joke arxiv papers in the field of astrophysics.  There are no joke arxiv papers in mathematics.  Please correct me if I'm wrong....Pretty please?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark That is interesting because in mathematics "the genius of Proust is that which he produced" holds most acutely. You cannot B.S a proof to someone actually trying to read it.

Answer (score 151):

There is a long tradition of posting joke papers to arXiv on or around April Fool's Day, especially in astro-ph - see the list below. The fact that all these papers were approved for arXiv offers some evidence (though not proof) that joke papers are okay.

It's probably best to limit joke papers to around April 1, though, when people know to be on the lookout for this stuff - or at least provide some indicator which is very clear to experts in the field that the paper is a joke, such as listing it as being submitted to Acta Prima Aprilia, [SIGBOVIK](https://sigbovik.org/), or the [Annals of Improbable Research](https://improbable.com/).

## A history of arXiv joke papers

(mirrored-ish [on my website](https://www.ellipsix.net/arxiv-joke-papers.html))

- [Superiority of the Lunar and Planetary Laboratory (LPL) over Steward Observatory (SO) at the University of Arizona](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0204013) (2002)
- [On the Utter Irrelevance of LPL Graduate Students: An Unbiased Survey by Steward Observatory Graduate Students](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0204041) (2002)
- [Cosmic Conspiracies](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0604011) (2006)
- [Natural Dark Energy](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0703783) (2007)
- [Down-sizing Forever](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4378) (2008)
- [Time variation of a fundamental dimensionless constant](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5321) (2009)
- [Galaxy Zoo: an unusual new class of galaxy cluster](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5377) (2009)
- [Orthographic Correlations in Astrophysics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.6064) (2010)
- [Schroedinger's Cat is not Alone](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4206) (2010)
- [Non-standard morphological relic patterns in the cosmic microwave background](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.6262) (2011)
- [On the influence of the Illuminati in astronomical adaptive optics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6708) (2012)
- [Gods as Topological Invariants](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6902) (2012)
- [The Proof of Innocence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0162) (2012)
- [On the Ratio of Circumference to Diameter for the Largest Observable Circles: An Empirical Approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0298) (2012)
- [Non-detection of the Tooth Fairy at Optical Wavelengths](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0492) (2012)
- [Pareidolic Dark Matter (PaDaM)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7262) (2013)
- [A search for direct heffalon production using the ATLAS and CMS experiments at the Large Hadron Collider](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7367) (2013)
- [Unidentified Moving Objects in Next Generation Time Domain Surveys](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7433) (2013)
- [Conspiratorial cosmology - the case against the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7476) (2013)
- [Common origin of superluminal neutrinos and DAMA annual modulation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0038) (2013)
- ["Winter is coming"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0445) (2013)
- [The CMB flexes its BICEPs while walking the Planck](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.8145) (2014)
- [Bayesian Prediction for The Winds of Winter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5830) (2014)
- [A Farewell to Falsifiability](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00108) (2015)
- [Beyond the New Horizon: The Future of Pluto](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00630) (2015)
- [Astrology in the Era of Exoplanets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09496) (2016)
- [An unexpected new explanation of seasonality in suicide attempts: Grey's Anatomy broadcasting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09590) (2016)
- [Pi in the sky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09703) (2016)
- [SET-E: The Search for Extraterrestrial Environmentalism](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09428) (2016)
- [Stopping GAN Violence: Generative Unadversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02528) (2017) (the example from the question, included for completeness)
- [A Neural Networks Approach to Predicting How Things Might Have Turned Out Had I Mustered the Nerve to Ask Barry Cottonfield to the Junior Prom Back in 1997](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10449) (2017)
- [On the Impossibility of Supersized Machines](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10987) (2017)
- [Detecting the Ultimate Power in the Universe with LSST](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10432) (2017)
- [Sitnikov in Westeros: How Celestial Mechanics finally explains why winter is coming in Game of Thrones](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11390) (2018)
- [Independent Discovery of a Sub-Earth in the Habitable Zone Around a Very Close Solar-Mass Star](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00419) (2018)
- [Colonel Mustard in the Aviary with the Candlestick: a limit cycle attractor transitions to a stable focus via supercritical Andronov-Hopf bifurcation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11559) (2018)
- [The Long Night: Modeling the Climate of Westeros](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.12195) (2019)
- [Worlds in Migration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.12437) (2019)
- [Forecasting Future Murders of Mr. Boddy by Numerical Weather Prediction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.12604) (2019)
- [A new kind of radio transient: ERBs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.12412) (2019)
- [Novel approach to Room Temperature Superconductivity problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14321) (2020)
- [Quantum Godwin's Law](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13715) (2020)
- [An Artificially-intelligent Means to Escape Discreetly from the Departmental Holiday Party; guide for the socially awkward](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14169) (2020)
- [The search for life and a new logic](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13981) (2020)
- [Making It Rain: How Giving Me Telescope Time Can Reduce Drought](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13879) (2020)
- [Searching for Space Vampires with TEvSS](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14345) (2020)
- [A PDF PSA, or Never gonna set_xscale again -- guilty feats with logarithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14327) (2020)
- [Defining the Really Habitable Zone](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13722) (2020)
- [Pandemic Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16572) (2021)
- ["I'll Finish It This Week" And Other Lies](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16574) (2021)
- [Using Artificial Intelligence to Shed Light on the Star of Biscuits: The Jaffa Cake](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16575) (2021)
- [The Swampland Conjecture Bound Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16583) (2021)
- [Detection of Rotational Variability in Floofy Objects at Optical Wavelengths](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16636) (2021)
- [I Knew You Were Trouble: Emotional Trends in the Repertoire of Taylor Swift](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16737) (2021)
- [Quantum analog of resource theory of stinginess](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16799) (2021)
- [The secret of the elixir of youth of blue straggler stars](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16866) (2021)
- [Science Spoofs, Physics Pranks and Astronomical Antics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17057) (2021)
- [My cat Chester's dynamical systems analysyyyyy7777777777777777y7is of the laser pointer and the red dot on the wall: correlation, causation, or SARS-Cov-2 hallucination?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17058) (2021)
- [The Swapland](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17198) (2021)
- ["My Rhodopsin!": Why Adding Dark Mode to Journals Could Make Us All Better Astronomers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16546) (2022)
- [Worry No More, The Hubble Tension is Relieved: A Truly Direct Measurement of the Hubble Constant from Mooniversal Expansion](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16551) (2022)
- [Could fresh lava be (warm) dark matter?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16563) (2022)
- [What's for Lunch? A systematic ordering of foods in the Soup-Salad-Sandwich phase space](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16580) (2022)
- [Taurine in Taurus. An Over-Caffeinated Search for Coffee in Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16598) (2022)
- [COWS all tHE way Down (COWSHED) I: Could cow based planetoids support methane atmospheres?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16609) (2022)
- [The popular myth of the drunk fireworks in the Valencian Fallas: "If you run, it chases you"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16630) (2022)
- [Predicting Winners of the Reality TV Dating Show $\textit{The Bachelor}$ Using Machine Learning Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16648) (2022)
- [The Parking Lot Planet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16791) (2022)
- [Social distancing between particles and objects in the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16982) (2022)
- [Transmogrifiers: Bright of the Exomoon](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17017) (2022)
- [On the Possibility of Discovering Exoplanets within our Solar System](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17075) (2022)
- [The Three Little Pigs and the Big Bad Wolf: Case Studies of Peer Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17095) (2022)
- [Follow the Index: A new proposal](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17123) (2022)
- [A Modest Proposal for the Non-existence of Exoplanets: The Expansion of Stellar Physics to Include Squars](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.16915) (2023)
- [When Tails Tell Tales](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.16941) (2023)
- [On The Planetary Theory of Everything](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17035) (2023)
- [As a matter of colon: I am NOT digging cheeky titles (no, but actually yes :>)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17059) (2023)
- [UFOs: Just Hot Air or Something Meteor?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17103) (2023)
- [Nuggets of Wisdom: Determining an Upper Limit on the Number Density of Chickens in the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17626) (2023)
- [ChatGPT scores a bad birdie in counting gravitational-wave chirps](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17628) (2023)
- [Chromaticity Effects on the Outcomes of Spheroid-based Scored Events](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17637) (2023)
- [Party Planning the Next True Happy New Year: Lunar Orbital Evolution Epochs with Integer Synodic Months Per Year](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17697) (2023)
- [Can AI Put Gamma-Ray Astrophysicists Out of a Job?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17853) (2023)
- [A Unified Nomenclature and Taxonomy for Planets, Stars, and Moons](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.18217) (2023)
- [MO0NFALL: The Great Filter and Exo-Moon Occurrence](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.18227) (2023)
- [Programmed but Arbitrary Control Minimization of Amplitude and phase for speckle Nulling (PACMAN)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.18231) (2023)
- [Macroscopic Dynamics of Entangled 3+1-Dimensional Systems: A Novel Investigation Into Why My MacBook Cable Tangles in My Backpack Every Single Day](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.00220) (2023)
- [Multi-Messenger Astrology](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19749) (2024)
- [Everything's Fine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19891) (2024)
- [Deeper Learning in Astronomy](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19937) (2024)
- [Is Winter Coming?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19977) (2024)
- [Why FLAMINGO is the perfect name for an array of Cherenkov telescopes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19993) (2024)
- [Unobserving the Moon: the spurious possibility of orbital decoupling due to solar neutrino Arago spot](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20087) (2024)
- [Echoes from a long time ago: Chewbacca inflation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20143) (2024)
- [FOOD I: A New Division Scheme For The Stelliferous Era](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20144) (2024)
- [Species Syzygy: Which Animal Has Seen the Most Total Solar Eclipses?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20175) (2024)
- [Circular reasoning: Solving the Hubble tension with a non-$π$ value of $π$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20219) (2024)
- [The Public Photometry Pipelines for Exoplanets](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20223) (2024)
- [In Violation of the Prime Directive: Simulating detriments to Delta-Quadrant civilizations from the starship Voyager's impact on planetary rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20268) (2024)
- [Vulcan: Retreading a Tired Hypothesis with the 2024 Total Solar Eclipse](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20281) (2024)
- [I'm in AGNi: A new standard for AGN pluralisation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20302) (2024)
- [pastamarkers: astrophysical data visualization with pasta-like markers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20314) (2024)
- [A Promising New Dark Matter Candidate, and Implications for the Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence (SETI)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.00465) (2024)
- [Scatophobic Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.00690) (2024)
- [Nishimori's self-tuning as evidence for the existence of God](https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.00919) (2024)
- [On the Superiority of the University of Arizona's Physics Club](https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.00975) (2024)

---

Note: since this has become what I think is the most comprehensive list of arXiv joke papers I know of, I've made it community wiki so anyone can add to the list. Any additions should be *clearly* joke papers and, in keeping with the topic of the question, must be posted *on arXiv*.

Comment: As another example there is also Donald Knuth's (quite hilarious) "The Complexity of Songs" which was published in ACM SIGACT - a quite serious and prestigious journal. So the tradition of posting joke papers does not just exist on arXiv but is a wider phenomenon at that.

Comment: -1, because I was planning on using my time productively before seeing this.  (+1!)

Comment: So how do non-experts know when they're reading a joke article? That sounds unprofessional and childish to me.

Comment: @CapeCode Articles on arXiv are targeted at experts. Other people generally won't understand what they're reading whether it's a joke or not.

Comment: The best joke paper of all times is Gates, V., et al. "Stuperspace." Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena 15.1-2 (1985): 289-293.  The published version is available here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167278985901733 and a free e-copy from here: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/Stuperspace.pdf. It predates arXiv.

Comment: Not on arXiv, but relevant: [Another article that makes bibliometric analysis a bit harder](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jpfeffer/papers/JPfeffer.pdf)

Comment: @DavidZ Does https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17060 count as "_clearly_ a joke"? After all, it's making fun of practices that apparently made it past referees of Nature and Science.

Comment: @Anyon Hmmm, good question... I read the paper and it does have some telltale signs of being intended as a joke, but it wasn't actually clear to me that it was a joke. Or maybe I should say I didn't get it. I mean, part of what typically makes a good joke paper is that it's funny even to non-experts. But that is not part of my stated criteion. So I'm on the fence about including that one, but I think if someone well versed in Majorana research can confirm that they would consider it clearly a joke, I'd put it on the list.

Answer (score 43):

Uploading joke papers to arXiv does not violate arXiv policy, according to this email sent by the arXiv moderation:

> ---------- Forwarded message ----------
>  From: arXiv Moderation  
> Date: Mon, Mar 13, 2017 at 4:38 PM
>  Subject:
>   [moderation #189697] Removing a joke paper
>  To: spamme@gmail.com
>
> Dear Spa,
>
> We will not remove this paper as it does not violate any of our
>   policies.
>
> -- [retracted name]
>  arXiv moderation
>
> On Sat Mar 11 18:27:47 2017, spamme@gmail.com wrote:
>
> > Dear arXiv-moderation,
> >
> > This paper is a joke paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02528 (it was
> >     submitted to an April 1st joke conference: http://sigbovik.org/2017).
> >
> > Could you please remove it from arXiv?
> >
> > Best,
> >     Spa Mme

This seems to be in contradiction with https://arxiv.org/help/moderation  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314164213/https://arxiv.org/help/moderation)):

> arXiv is distinct from the web as a whole, because **arXiv contains exclusively scientific research content**. Although arXiv is open to submissions from the scientific communities, our team has worked behind the scenes for a long time to ensure the quality of our content.
>
> arXiv moderators will suggest the removal of a submission that violates arXiv policies in some way. Potential reasons for removal are: Inappropriate format. arXiv accepts only submissions in the form of an article that would be refereeable by a conventional publication venue. This excludes […] papers that contain inflammatory or **fictitious content**, papers that use highly dramatic and mis-representative titles/abstracts/introductions.

Comment: That might be slightly surprising. In ArXiv moderation system page we read: 
"arXiv is distinct from the web as a whole, because arXiv contains *exclusively scientific research content.*" and "arXiv is an openly accessible, moderated repository for scholarly papers in specific scientific disciplines. Material submitted to arXiv is expected to be of interest, relevance, and value to those disciplines. arXiv reserves the right to reject or reclassify any submission." 

I wonder why ArXiv moderators classify clear joke papers as scholarly papers with scientific content.

Comment: @PsySp Yes I was surprised too (and disappointed). I wonder what it takes to be an arXiv-approved joke.

Comment: Maybe these excerpts from the Moderation page of ArXiv should be added to your answer because it seem they directly contradict the answer you received from the moderator!
https://arxiv.org/help/moderation
(It is even in bold!)

Comment: @PsySp Sounds good, added. Apparently a joke isn't fictitious content, but is scientific research content.

Answer (score 42):

*The arXiv (pronounced "archive")is a repository of electronic preprints, known as e-prints, of scientific papers in the fields of mathematics, physics, astronomy, computer science, quantitative biology, statistics, and quantitative finance, which can be accessed online.*

So, *please* do not upload *joke* papers. These papers are not helping the community, and they are not helping the authors of such papers.

Having said that, if the paper has *any* scientific value, even if it is a funny paper, then it is more than welcome. TCS has a conference called [FUN with algorithms](http://www2.idsia.ch/cms/fun16/) the purpose of which is to publish amusing papers with certain algorithmic flavor.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I mean, in case the authors use their real names (which I doubt). In any case I do not see why anybody would want to create noise as you say.

Comment: I'm an arXiv moderator, and I disagree with this answer.

Comment: @JeffE please post your own answer?

Comment: @JeffE A good recipe to receove something like my last "Our volunteer moderators determined that your article does not contain sufficient original or substantive research to merit inclusion within arXiv.   Resubmission of removed papers may result in the loss of your submission privileges."

Comment: @smci I have added an email sent by the arXiv moderation as an answer.

Comment: @PsySp: It wasn't intended as a personal comment, but if it came across that way then I apologise. That said, I do think there's a need to distinguish between entertaining papers written by researchers in a field for the amusement of other researchers in the field (which to my mind are, and should be, welcome on arXiv, if not to excess), and spam papers that have nothing to do with the field in question, or contain junk text. In this case, the authors are serious guys writing under their own names, who've put effort into making the paper entertaining to their community.

Comment: It's actually not so easy to do well, and it's somewhat risky if (as in the case of one of the guys) you're well-known in the field - in this case, I think they've judged it carefully and got the balance right.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz My opinion is that a joke paper, published under Machine Learning tag, is borderline qualified for spam. There are many other places where such a paper would be more appreciated and could potentially invoke less inconveniences. Because, sometimes, it's hard to judge if it's a clear joke or not.

Comment: @PsySp: I think it's subjective - let's move on.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz If you are well-known but take your reputation lightly then it is not very risky. Well-known people are HARDER to get sacked, not easier!

Answer (score 2):

Also, realize that people have done this to real journals.  Consider the Sokol hoax. Or the famous math paper about big game hunting mocking. Or the more subtle Physical Review Letter co-author [F. D. C. Willard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._D._C._Willard)

I would avoid doing it too much.  And if it gets done too much it will damage the resource.  That said, a little bit is kind of amusing.  Especially if skillfully done.  But some pepper is good...too much is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the paper ["An Explicit Conjectured Determinant Evaluation Whose Proof Would Make Me Happy (and the OEIS richer)"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1532) by Doron Zeilberger
a joke paper, or at least a troll paper.

There are no false statements or non-research in the paper.
The issue is that Zeilberger (cleverly) hides the fact that a solution to his problem also solves the very famous Collatz conjecture.
So people trying to solve the problem stated in his paper are very likely to waste their time on a problem that is way harder than it seems.

On the other hand, there could be a [George Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig) moment a solution is easier found if one believes that the problem is solvable. Dantzig famously mistook two open problems in statistics for class homework, and turned in the solutions a few days later.

Answer (score 0):

It does happen, but there are also humorous journals you may also submit to, especially if it is satirical as the Annals of Improbable research will only accept real research that's funny.

I ran across this because I maintain one, The Journal of Astrological Big Data Ecology (Jabde.com) where we also host The Journal of Immaterial Science which tends to involve more chemistry humor. If anyone runs across this, we always accept paper submissions and do actually publish the really good ones.